# Align divs horizontally with infinite height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to align 3 or more `div` elements horizontally with infinite height containing sub `div`.

```
 <div class ="container">
  <div class ="left">//sub divs</div>
  <div class ="center">// some random number of sub divs</div>
  <div class ="right"> // sub divs here</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container { 
    width: 80%;
} 
.left, .right { 
    width: 50%;
}
```

Now the `center` is fully visible and `left`, `right` is visible `200px` each.  When I click the `center` or `left`, `right` div should slide to the `center` shifting the respective `div` aside and should be fully visible.

How can I achieve this design?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/xjpL333r/

Comment: Could you be more clear on what you are trying to achieve? I am unsure what _"shifting the respective div aside and should be fully visible."_ means? When you say _"fully visible"_ what do you mean? Are the divs hidden? Or do you want them to be the full width?

Comment: To accomplish this you might want to look into documentation on javascript or jquery.

Comment: @zgood my container width is 80% of the screen.  And the. Center,  right,  left divs are 50% of container.  So when my center div is in center of container.  Right and left div are partially visible due to overflow hidden property of container.

Comment: @kishoresahas you get nearly to what I needed.  But in my case I need the Container to be 80% of screen.

Comment: just change width 80% http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/xjpL333r/2/

Comment: But center left and right should be 50%.

Comment: 50% of what , `container` ?   so where is the space for `center` as 50% + 50% = 100% of the parent element

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to explain.  Left(half right side visible)  should take 25% of container.  Center(fully visible)  should be 50% of container.  Right(half left side visible)  should be 25%.  So 25% + 50 % + 25% = 100%

Comment: so you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/xjpL333r/5/ ?

Comment: and you mean fully visible in the sense , if left is clicked it should be 100% of container ?

Comment: It should look like that but NO.  The WIDTH of the CENTER,  RIGHT, LEFT should be same.  Right and left should acquire 25% of container without changing its width.

Comment: Fully visible in sense acquire 50% of container.  Because width of Center = right = left =.5 container

Comment: just out of curiosity,  are looking for a slider kind of ? some what like http://www.jssor.com/demos/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.slider

Comment: Exactly.  That's kind of thing I needed but how to do with  div containing text and html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class ="container">
    <div class="left">ONE</div>
    <div class="center">TWO</div>
    <div class="right">THREE</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px #000 solid;
    font-size: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.container > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #8FB8ED;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #8FB8ED;
}

.center {
    left: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #3590F3;
}
```

JS / JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container > div').on('click', function() {
        var pos = $(this).attr('class');
        if (pos !== 'center') {
            $(this).closest('.container').find('.center')
                .removeClass('center')
                .addClass(pos);
            $(this).removeClass(pos).addClass('center');
        }
    });
});
```

Try this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j20ycsu0/1/

Comment: Almost.  But. It should look like that but NO.  The WIDTH of the CENTER,  RIGHT, LEFT should be same.  Right and left should acquire 25% of container without changing width.

Comment: Hm. Try this : https://jsfiddle.net/j20ycsu0/2/
I set the width to 50% for each .container > div. Width of the divs are now the same. Left and right are now out of the .container but keep their size. What do you mean by "Right and left should acquire 25% of container without changing width." ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking for.  Kind of 

Comment: Great :) ! Do I need to add some comments to the code ?